# Spectrum of an unbounded operator $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Are there any reference that we can find the following

**Theorem:**  Let $A$ be a positive (resp. negative) self-adjoint unbounded operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Then, the spectrum of $A$ is contained in
the positive real-axis (resp. negative real-axis).

Comment: Why do you ask about "unbounded operator" in the title?

Comment: Yes, it's an unbounded operator. I edited my question. Thanks

Comment: Strictly saying, the definition of a self-adjoint operator includes being "bounded." If your operator is unbounded then it is not self-adjoint. Anyway, a very readable and rigorous discussion is given in [Linear Operator Theory in Engineering and Science](https://www.amazon.com/Operator-Engineering-Science-Mathematical-Sciences/dp/038795001X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1471700598&sr=8-2&keywords=linear+operators).

Comment: @Artem : If $A : \mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq H \rightarrow H$ is a closed, densely-defined linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$, then the adjoint $A^*$ is also a closed, densely-defined linear operator. And it is quite possible to have $A=A^*$, which is what selfadjoint is defined to be in this context.

Comment: @TrialAndError Then it looks like it depends on the definition. Say in the book I referenced above selfadjoint must be defined *everywhere*, and the operator that you are talking about is called *symmetric.*

Comment: @Artem There is a difference between symmetric and selfadjoint for closed densely-defined linear operators. Such an $A$ is symmetric if $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x,Ay\rangle$ for all $x,y\in\mathcal{D}(A)$. The adjoint $A^*$ of $A$ has a domain consisting of all $y$ for which there exists $z$ such that $\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x,z\rangle$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$. Then one defines $A^*y = z$. In terms of graphs, one has $\mathcal{G}(A) \subseteq\mathcal{G}(A^*)$ if $A$ is symmetric, but $A=A^*$ means $\mathcal{G}(A)=\mathcal{G}(A^*)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $A : \mathcal{D}(A) \subset H\rightarrow H$ is an unbounded selfadjoint operator on a real or complex Hilbert space $H$ such that $(Ax,x) \ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$. For $\lambda > 0$,
$$
         \lambda(x,x) \le ((A+\lambda I)x,x)\le \|(A+\lambda I)x\|\|x\|,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(A).
$$
Therefore,
$$
                 \lambda\|x\| \le \|(A+\lambda I)x\|,\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(A).
$$
Such an inequality forces the range of $A+\lambda I$ to be closed because because, if $(A+\lambda I)x_n$ converges to $y$, then $\{ (A+\lambda I)x_n \}$ is a Cauchy sequence and the above forces $\{ x_n \}$ to be a Cauchy sequence, which must converge to some $x$ because $H$ is complete. Then, because $A$ is closed, $y = (A+\lambda I)x$. So the range of $A+\lambda I$ is closed. The range of $A+\lambda I$ must be all of $X$ because it is closed and $y \in \mathcal{R}(A+\lambda I)^{\perp}$ iff
$$
             ((A+\lambda I)x,y)=0,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(A).
$$
By the definition of adjoint, $y \in \mathcal{D}(A^*)=\mathcal{D}(A)$ and $(A+\lambda I)y=0$. However, $\mathcal{N}(A+\lambda I)=\{0\}$ which gives $y=0$. Hence, $-\lambda\in\rho(A)$, as was to be shown.